# REST web service versioning - deprecation period

Tags: java, web-services, rest, versioning

How can I implement deprecation period as implemented by Facebook for its Marketing API?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/versions

How are the older version of the web services deprecated after the period of 90 days?

Comment: Typically, you would deploy multiple versions of the same service.  How you choose to distinguish the versions is up to you.  Generally it is done via namespaces for SOAP, or URL for REST.  Once the deprecated version has expired it can be undeployed.

Comment: That means we would need an additional deployment to remove the deprecated web service versions.

Comment: Unless you're using a microservice strategy, yes, you would need another deployment.  The document you reference never talks about deployment strategy.  There's no reason to assume they aren't doing the same thing.  The only other option would be to make your service layer "smart" enough to fail on services that are no longer supposed to work.